# Mad Libs javascript code not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a Madlibs game but I'm having problems with all of the values being inserted in to the story. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Assignment 2 </title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/assignment02.js"></script>


        </head>

            <body>

                <h1>The Wizard of Oz!</h1>
                    <p> <strong><span id="femaleName1"></span></strong> lived in the midst of the great <strong><span id="stateName"></span></strong> <strong><span id="geoFeature"></span></strong> , with Uncle <strong><span id="maleName"></span></strong> , who was a <strong><span id="jobName"></span></strong> , and Aunt <strong><span id="femaleName2"></span></strong>, who was the farmer's wife. Their house was small, for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles. There were four walls, a floor and a roof, which made one room; and this room contained a rusty looking <strong><span id="noun1"></span></strong>, a <strong><span id="noun2"></span></strong> for the dishes, a table, three or four chairs, and the beds. Uncle <strong><span id="maleName"></span></strong> and Aunt <strong><span id="femaleName2"></span></strong> had a big bed in one corner, and <strong><span id="femaleName1"></span></strong>a little bed in another corner. There was no garret at all, and no cellar--except a small hole dug in the ground, called a cyclone cellar, where the family would go in case one of those great whirlwinds arose, mighty enough to crush any building in its path. It was reached by a trap door in the middle of the <strong><span id="noun3"></span></strong>, from which a ladder led down into the small, dark hole.

                    </p>

                    <p>When <strong><span id="femaleName1"></span></strong> stood in the doorway and looked around, she could see nothing but the great <strong><span id="colorName"></span></strong> <strong><span id="geoFeature"></span></strong> on every side. Not a <strong><span id="noun4"></span></strong> nor a <strong><span></span></strong> broke the broad sweep of flat country that reached to the edge of the sky in all directions. The sun had baked the plowed land into a <strong><span id="noun5"></span></strong> mass, with little cracks running through it. Even the grass was not green, for the sun had burned the tops of the long blades until they were the same <strong><span id="colorName"></span></strong> color to be seen everywhere. Once the house had been painted, but the sun blistered the paint and the rain washed it away, and now the house was as dull and <strong><span id="colorName"></span></strong> as everything else. 

                    </p>

            </body>
    </html>
```

My Javascript is this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var femaleName1 = prompt("Please enter a female's first name (1 of 2)");
        var stateName = prompt("Please enter the name of a State");
        var geoFeature = prompt("Please enter a geographical feature");
        var maleName = prompt("Please enter a male's first name");
        var jobName = prompt("Please enter an occupation");
        var femaleName2 = prompt("Please enter another female's first name (2 of 2)");
        var noun1 = prompt("Please enter a noun (1 of 5)");
        var noun2 = prompt("Please enter a noun (2of 5)");
        var noun3 = prompt("Please enter a noun (3 of 5)");
        var colorName = prompt("Please enter a color");
        var noun4 = prompt("Please enter a noun (4 of 5)");
        var noun5 = prompt("Please enter a noun (5 of 5)");

            $("#femaleName1").text(femaleName1);
            $("#stateName").text(stateName);
            $("#geoFeature").text(geoFeature);
            $("#maleName").text(maleName);
            $("#jobName").text(jobName);
            $("#femaleName2").text(femaleName2);
            $("#noun1").text(noun1);
            $("#noun2").text(noun2);
            $("#noun3").text(noun3);
            $("#colorName").text(colorName);
            $("#noun4").text(noun4);
            $("#noun5").text(noun5);
});
```

The problem I'm having is not all of the values are being inserted in to the story. For example, after "three or four chairs, and the beds." the value of the male and female2 don't show up. There should be a total of 20 inputs but only 12 of them show up. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi Scotty, you only have 12 prompts in the example? Where are the other 8?

Answer (score 0):

An id should be unique in HTML, if you wan't to select multiple elements, you should use class or [data attributes (data-*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

I made an exemple with both working here https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-butterfly-kkjno